# MaterialApp builder Method places shadow/gradient around widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `MaterialApp` with several routes for the various section of my application.

**Description**

I have used the `builder` method of the `MaterialApp` class to place a single scaffold around all of my routes.

The `body` of this scaffold is a `Row` which contains a custom side menu widget, and the `Widget` from the `MaterialApp`'s `builder` method.

**Problem**

Flutter is placing a shadow/gradient between my side menu (the widget from the builder method) and the main body of the application. I do not want this shadow and I do not know how to remove it.

What it looks like at the moment:

[image]

What it should look like:

[image]

This photo shows the difference between the two results (look at the right hand side of the side menus):

[image]

Comment: Can you include code-snippet that will reproduce the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

What is the top widget in your routes?

This looks like some default elevation is applied by material. You might (worst case) want to wrap the child within the builder method with a ClipRRect or DecoratedBox with specified clip behaviour to avoid that shadow overlaying your other widgets

Comment: Perhaps, I will try this. I am not sure to be honest how I should handle having a single Scaffold above my navigation? I want the user to be able to navigate between routes within my application, but have a single scaffold persist - what is the best way to do this @Inf0rmatix ?

Comment: I like using go_router. It offers a navigationBuilder function. In that context you've got the router already inside your build context but get to wrap the displayed page in whatever widgets you like.

That's where you can wrap it with a single scaffold.